# Square Brackets after function execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the purpose/ how does it work when declaring a function like:

```
myObj.request({myParam: null })[something](from, (error, res, body){
   //code
})
```

What is the behavior of this code? I don't get the meaning of `[something]` and the anonymous function that follows

Comment: `myObj.request({myParam: null })` returns an array or object. `myObj.request({myParam: null })[something]` returns the element at index `something`.

Comment: as @jabaa I believe the `request` returns an array

Comment: @frostzt and you can still access an array's members with square bracket notation. Arrays are also objects. So, it hardly matters that the result is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know the implementation details of your posted code so i can just guess:

`myObj.request()` will return an array/object of functions. With `[something]` you will select one of those functions and invoke it afterwards. As said, thats only guessing whats going on as you didnt provide any context. For example:

```
const myObj = {
  request: () => ({ 
    a: () => console.log('i am fn a'), 
    b: () => console.log('i am fn b'), 
  })
}

myObj.request()['a']() // console.logs 'i am fn a'
```

NOTE: for simplicity reasons i did not pass any arguments/callbacks to the functions. If you still have questions let me know and i'll update the answer

Comment: It is the [request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestdefaultsoptions). So I guess it's invoking the GET method. and `from` is the first argument.

Comment: ah yes, it states in the docs > This method returns a wrapper around the normal request API that defaults to whatever options you pass to it.
so you are correct with something = 'get' or any other fn name of the request lib and from are your usual request args followed by the request callback

Answer (score 1):

Javascript evaluates the expression inside square bracket, in your case the value for `something` and will executes the function with that name.

For example in your case

```
myObj.request({myParam: null })[something]
```

If the value of `something` is `"get"` as string. It will simply executes

```
myObj.request({myParam: null })["get"]
```

OR

```
myObj.request({myParam: null }).get
```

Its just like accessing a prperty inside an object, where `myObj.request({myParam: null })` is the object and value for `something` is the property inside that object.

Comment: It's not a computed property name, it's just plain [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets). More technically called "property accessor". Computed property names come into play when *constructing* an object `obj = {[something]: "hello"}`

Comment: Now i can understand everything. Thank you both!